# Node.js - Pegar parâmetro de URL via Jade

Tags: node.js, express.js

Tenho a seguinte url `http://localhost:3000/user/index/1`, gostaria de conseguir pegar o último parâmetro. Tentei com `- var name = window.location.pathname;` colocando no arquivo .jade e não funcionou, mas se for possível fazer um redirect com envio de parâmetros como no `.render()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
notification: request.params.message
```

Este modo está em desuso:

```
notification: request.param('message','')
```